# How I can configure my Intranet-connecting VPN connention not to be used for connecting into anything outside of it?

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-mate

I have setup an Openvpn connection via network-manager on Ubuntu Mate 18.04LTS, the VPN is used for connecting into remote server via ssh without the need for having public-facing servers, the server serves a company intranet.

But when I connect into the server I am unable to connect into internet because the VPN server has no rules for directing the traffic into the internet. This behaviour is the expected one.

So how I can configure the vpn connection in order NOT to disconnect from the internet when I connect into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For Greek System Language look into the screenshots)

On the network manager settings select your VPN connection

> [image: Selecting OpenVPN Connection]
>
> [image: Add configuration for OpenVPn connection]

Then go into IPV4 Settings -> Routes

> [image: What to select for configuring the routes]:

And then select the "Use this connection only for resources on its network".

> [image: Select setting for resource only connections]

Press OK and recconect into VPN.